# Docker ENTRYPOINT behaving differently from --entrypoint option

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-image-base

COPY src src

RUN chmod +x src/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ['/src/script.sh']
```

After successful build:

```
docker run created_image

/bin/sh: [/src/script.sh]: No such file or directory
```

```
docker run --entrypoint /src/script.sh created_image

script runs successfully
```

I feel like I'm overwriting the default ENTRYPOINT with the same thing but it behaves differently. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not the same thing, because your `ENTRYPOINT` is invalid.

`ENTRYPOINT` has two forms:

- The shell command form:

  `ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2`
- and the `exec` form:

  `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`

Which of the two forms are you using here? If you answer "the second", you have been subtly led astray, because you have **single-quotes** `'` there instead of **double-quotes** `"`!

As specified in the docs:

> **Note:** The `exec` form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (`"`) around words not single-quotes (`'`).

**So, you *actually* have the first form, the shell command form.**

Docker will pass your "command" to the shell, like this:

```sh
/bin/sh -c "['/src/script.sh']"
```

Due to the way quotes work when parsing shell command lines, this ends up being equivalent to typing `[/src/script.sh]` into your shell. The shell then rightfully complains that that's not a valid command.